# SharePoint 2010 FBA Access Denied for Forms Users

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, central-administration

I setup SharePoint 2010 FBA using ASP Net Membership database following the article: [Step by Step Guide to Configure SharePoint 2010 Forms Based Authentication with SQL](http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/step-by-step-guide-to-configure-sharepoint-2010-forms-based-authentication-with-sql/).

I configured all web.config files of **Central Admin**, **External Site**, **SecurityToken Web Service** on the WFEs in sections: ConnectionStrings, PeoplePickerWildcards, RoleManagers, and MembershipProviders.  The default providers all seem to be setup correctly because I can see users in the People Picker.  I also ensured FBAService account has access to the membership database.

I am able to log-in to the external site using Windows Authentication (see image below) but with Forms Authentication I keep getting error (also see image directly below):

***The server could not sign you in. Make sure your user name and password are correct, and then try again.***

I've spent over a week troubleshooting this, sometimes starting over completely from scratch!

One thing I found interesting is if I set the `defaultProvider` to "i" and "c" for the external site, I can't manage users in IIS!  However, when I set it to "ExternalMembershipProvider" and "ExternalRoleManager" I can!!

I also tried SQL Profiler but didn't see anything that stood out.  Hmmm... I'm seeing this in the logs...

```
09/07/2012 20:08:25.14  w3wp.exe (0x3084)                           0x1218  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           0000    Unexpected  Password check on 'admin' generated exception: 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException]: The security token username and password could not be validated. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException: The security token username and password could not be validated.).'.    
09/07/2012 20:08:25.14  w3wp.exe (0x3084)                           0x1218  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           fo1t    Monitorable SPSecurityTokenService.Issue() failed: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException]: The security token username and password could not be validated. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.FailedAuthenticationException: The security token username and password could not be validated.).   
09/07/2012 20:08:25.14  w3wp.exe (0x17B0)                           0x3BBC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           fsq7    High        Request for security token failed with exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The security token username and password could not be validated.     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.ReadResponse(Message response)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo)  eaf3b387-bcd4-4ad0-956b-9f7ce24b5681
09/07/2012 20:08:25.14  w3wp.exe (0x17B0)                           0x3BBC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           8306    Critical    An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The security token username and password could not be validated..    eaf3b387-bcd4-4ad0-956b-9f7ce24b5681
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: AFAIK the default provide should not be set to anything other than `i` and `c` for any site, and you should use `FBA Authentication pack(http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/documentation)` to manage the users.Additionally , check your settings with the following `http://blogs.technet.com/b/mahesm/archive/2010/04/07/configure-forms-based-authentication-fba-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx`. Another useful link is `http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/`

Comment: If you can't use a third party tool to manage your FBA users, what I tend to do is to create a new, empty application in IIS, hook up the FBA Membership and Role providers, and use that application to manage the users.

Comment: @JamesLove thanks!  I have been using this one: http://sp2010fba.codeplex.com/ and it works great!

Comment: Neat, will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out and I would love to save anyone from this headache.  I opened all mentioned web.config's on both WFEs and had to make sure the `<machineKey>` generated was the exact same.  Everything else was perfect.

Also, since you're here let me tell you that this FBA Management Tool here works great!!

http://sp2010fba.codeplex.com/

Cheers!